# Maven : Remove target folder after build

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a Spring project with a Parent and 2 sub-modules

```
   Parent
    -- mod1
    -- mod2
```

I want to build from the parent but the mod1 should not create a target folder( or should get deleted immediately after the build succeeds). How can I achieve this?

My goal is to make it's brother(mod2) to absorb the jar into it's lib and not "expose" the target folder of mod1 outside.

I have gone through multiple SO posts and articles on net but could not find something to help me effectively.

mod1 pom is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>library-complete</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>multi-module-library-complete</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

> Note: removing the build tag did not achieve my goal either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `should not create a target folder` what is the problem with that? That's the default of Maven? Is there a problem? Apart from that you can delete that after you build via `mvn clean`??

Comment: none in particular, but some teams have requested for a single target folder as it makes it less confusing, so was hoping to avoid creating multiple targets.

Comment: Teach your team how Maven works. It's easier to use the convention instead configuring things (conventions over configuration)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `target` directory is Maven's working directory (even with a plugin, there is probably not a good way to delete it while the build is running).

Instead, you should run `mvn clean` once the first build is finished, and build artifacts have been moved to another location.

```bash
@echo off

REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM -- Build the project
call mvn clean package
set "RETURN_VAL=%ERRORLEVEL%"
if [1]==[%RETURN_VAL%] goto error
if [0]==[%RETURN_VAL%] goto success

REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM -- Take any action required for a failed build
:error
goto end

REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:success
REM -- Copy build artifacts to project root (or another location of your choice)
cp "./target/Project.jar" "./Project.jar"

REM -- Remove the target directory
call mvn clean
goto end

REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:end
pause
```